# kdb - get column values n days ago

Tags: kdb

If I have a table of prices

```
t:([]date:2018.01.01+til 30;px:100+sums 30?(-1;1))

date    px
2018.01.01  101
2018.01.02  102
2018.01.03  103
2018.01.04  102
2018.01.05  103
2018.01.06  102
2018.01.07  103
...
```

how do I compute the returns over `n` days? I am interested in both computing
`(px[i] - px[i-n])/px[i-n]` and `(px[date] - px[date-n])/px[date-n]`, i.e. one where the column `px` is shifted `n` slots by index and one where the previous price is the price at `date-n`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you've pretty much got it right with the first one. To get the returns you can use this lambda:

```
{update return1:(px-px[i-x])%px[i-x] from t}[5]
```

For the date shift you can use an aj like this:

```
select date,return2:(px-pr)%pr from aj[`date;t;select date,pr:px from update date:date+5 from t]
```

Basically what you are trying to do here is to shift the date by the number of days you want to and then extract the price. You use an `aj` to create your table which will look something like this:

```
q)aj[`date;t;select date,pr:px from update date:date+5 from t]
date       px pr
----------------
2018.01.01 99 98
2018.01.02 98 97
2018.01.03 97 98
```

Where px is your price now and pr is your price 5 days from now.

Then the return is calculated just the normal way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: cool thanks. I also just found out about `xprev`: `update prevPx:n xprev px from t`

Comment: There is a little typo in your solution, it should be + not -:
`aj[\`date;t;select date,pr:px from update date:date+5 from t]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It has to be plus there indeed.